# Database backup or restore working only when I place |DataDirectory| connection string into app.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-backups

I am using visual studio 2012 service base database. I think it backup because I saw a .BAK file but when I restore, its not working. Both have no error on runtime but I think theres something wrong with my code. Here's my code:

```
private void btnBackUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)           
    {
        try
        {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            progressBar1.Value = 15;
            bool bBackUpStatus = true;

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;

            if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent"))
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak"))
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show(@"Do you want to replace it?", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        File.Delete(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak");
                    }
                    else
                        bBackUpStatus = false;
                }
            }
            else
                Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent");

            if (bBackUpStatus)
            {


                con.Open();

                progressBar1.Value = 25;

                string path1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"SchoolDatabase.mdf");

                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("backup database [" + path1 + @"] to disk ='D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak' with init,stats=10", con);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                progressBar1.Value = 35;
                con.Close();

                timer1.Start();

                MessageBox.Show("Backup of the Database saved Successfully", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                timer1.Stop();
                progressBar1.Value = 10;
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Backup Error, Please close the software & restart and then try again to backup", "Backup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar1.Value = 15;

        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak"))
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you restore?", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    progressBar1.Value = 25;
                    SqlCommand cmd;
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("use master", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    progressBar1.Value = 35;
                    string path1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"SchoolDatabase.mdf");
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("restore database [" + path1 + @"] from disk = 'D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak'", con);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    timer1.Start();
                    MessageBox.Show("Database has been Restored", "Restoration", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    timer1.Stop();
                    progressBar1.Value = 10;
                    progressBar1.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(@"This is not in the correct path, Please close the software & restart and then try again to restore", "Restoration", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 50;
            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            if (progressBar1.Value <= progressBar1.Maximum)
                timer1.Stop();

            progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Maximum;
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

Below is my connection string :

```
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolManagement.Properties.Settings.SchoolDatabaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\Users\ARORAS\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SchoolManagement\SchoolManagement\SchoolDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1" />
</startup>
```

But when I changed my connection string to |DataDirectory| backup and restore both worked properly. as below

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SchoolDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

But I don't want to use |DataDirectory| string. Please suggest what to change in the backup and restore code? Please help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I am providing the answer here if any one in future get the same problem.
One thing is noticeable that there are 2 databases in a project i.e. one database is main app directory database and another is output database. When we start debugging, main database copies all tables and its data into the output directory database typically `\bin\Debug\database.mdf`. So, If we use `|DataDirectory|` in connection string, the backup will work perfectly but this is not a good way because by doing this we are restoring the all data into the \bin database which for just output. So, we should provide conncetion string full as below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolManagement.Properties.Settings.SchoolDatabaseConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\Users\ABC\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SchoolManagement\SchoolManagement\SchoolDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Remember that this is for VS service base database connection string.
And we have to write the full path of our main database in backup form's path string. see below:

```
string path1 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"G:\Users\ABC\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SchoolManagement\SchoolManagement\SchoolDatabase.mdf");
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("backup database [" + path1 + @"] to disk ='D:\Backup_MAConvent\MAConvent_Backup.bak' with init,stats=10", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```